# Simulating a DC motor with a constant friction torque

Tags: motor, dc, load, torque, simulink

I'm trying to simulate a DC motor with simulink. The problem is that I don't know how to take a load torque into account. If the DC motor drives a wheel with constant velocity, there will be a constant frictional force working against the DC motor. How would this be implemented in a DC-motor simulink simulation?

[image]

I have tried subtracting a load torque in between the two transferfunction blocks but then the simulated motor speed is always goes negative.

Comment: Constant torque means constant current. I don't see you modelling current yet, it's all hidden in K.

Comment: @Janka I believe the current is modeled by the \$\frac1{R+Ls}\$ part.

Comment: "*there will be a constant frictional force working against the DC motor*" is an error. Retarding force on a motor is load + friction + windage. Friction and windage effectively go to zero at zero speed. (For your purposes).  friction + windage go negative at negative speeds. Each follow some curve on ether side.....

Answer (score 1):

Your block Kt/(R+Ls) is torque. V/(R+Ls) is your current. Kt is torque per amp (Nm/A). You simply add a value after Kt/(R+Ls), if it's constant. Unfortunately, many loads are speed or position dependent and then it get's much more complicated (math wise). Model-wise it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a high enough constant torque to a stalled motor, you will end up turning it in the opposite direction, so a negative speed may well be physical. For starters, try applying less load torque and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding less torque and the results gave much more sense now. But as i've realized the load torque should not be a constant value from the beginning (in the case of a wheel starting to turn in contact with the ground). The static friction increases as the forward force increases until the wheel starts turning. Is there a way to make an input like this in simulink? (an input that increases by the same amount as the forward force/torque and then stops once it reaches a given maximal value)